# Не получается залить проект на GitHub

Tags: git, android-studio, github

При попытке залить проект на GitHub из Android Studio, а именно выбираю Share Project On GitHub, ругается "git repository with selected name already exists" и естественно кнопка Share не активна. 
Перевод ругательства: "Репозиторий с таким именем уже существует" и что?
На сайт GitHub захожу без проблем и Test GitRepository URL проходит.

Comment: тебе надо не "расшарить проект на гитхабе", а просто добавить гитхабовский remote. https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/. при расшаривании он пытается создать новый репозиторий, видимо. ну или удали его и расшарь

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя актуальный проект на локальной машине, который ты уже хочешь залить на github, то просто удали репозиторий с самого github'a и проделай те же действия снова.

или

Если у тебя есть дополнения к уже существуещему проекту, которые ты хочешь просто доЗалить на github то используй VCS(commit changes) или же Terminal, в котором стоит прописать следующее

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Some comments"
git push origin название текущей ветки(по умолчанию master)
```